# Как вывести CardView по центру?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

В программе использую RecyclerView. Написал для него адаптер. ViewHolder содержит CardView с картинкой внутри. Мне нужно выводить эти CardView в две колонки, вертикально. Для этого GridLayoutManager с двумя колонками. Всё работает. Но мне нужно, чтобы CardView выводились колонках по центру, у меня CardView прижимаются к левому краю. Подскажите, как отцентрировать CardView внутри RecyclerView с использованием 2-х колонок GridLayoutManager?

это разметка элемента RecyclerView

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewPerson"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPerson"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/im1" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

Это разметка активити с RecyclerView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentStudent">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPersons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Это код подключения recyclerView

```
RecyclerView recyclerViewPersons = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPersons);
ArrayList<Person> setPersons = new SetPersons().getArrayPersons();
RecyclerView.Adapter adapterPerson = new AdapterPersons(setPersons, getContext());
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
recyclerViewPersons.setAdapter(adapterPerson);
recyclerViewPersons.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CardView прижаты к левому краю

Comment: Можете показать ваш результат и желаемый?

Comment: @guerrk1n поправил вопрос. Вот мой результат. Мне нужно, чтобы cardView не прижимались к левому краю, а располагались по центру каждой колонки

Comment: Попробуйте в макете с recyclerview поменять LinearLayout на ConstraintLayout с соответствующими привязками.

Answer (score 1):

Очень сложно понять что именно вам нужно, без вашей разметки. Но я все же попробую вам интуитивно помочь. Создал разметку для элемента списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

и вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть то что вам нужно спрятано в этой строке:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: поправил вопрос. CardView прижимаются к левому краю. Нужно их расположить по центру каждой колонки. Я предполагаю, что нужен метод располагающий содержимое GridLayoutManager по центру.

Comment: я думаю это зависит от разметки элемента списка, вы пробовали мой вариант?

Comment: я поправил свой вопрос. Там я выложил свою разметку. Она такая же как у вас.

Comment: а что если попробовать у элемента списка ширину сделать равной родителю или fill_parent, что-то изменится?

Comment: сделал ширину CardView - match_parent. CardView растянулись на половину экрана. Картинка осталась в центре каждого CardView. Но мне это не подходит.  Нужно, чтобы CardView был размером 120*120 (как картинка). И располагался по центру

Comment: а если у списка android:layout_gravity="center" поставить что-то изменится?

Comment: нет не меняется.

Comment: Решил упростить задачу. Поменял GridLayoutManager на LinearLayoutManager. В результате все CardView прижались к левому краю. Даже layout_gravity = "right" не помогает.

Comment: предполагаю, что тут нужны настройки LayoutManager. Это ведь он располагает CardView внутри себя?

Comment: @ Andrew, Кажется разобрался. Мой CardView (в макете) не находится ни в одном из Layout. Я добавил в корень FrameLayout. И CardView (находящийся внутри него) сразу стал управляться layout_gravity!!! Меня сбило одно обучающее видео, в котором лектор создал CardView в корень макета. Но он не касался возможности перемещения этого CardView  в нужное место. Теперь я понял, что без корневого Layout это невозможно